# Designing your own robot using ROS platform

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do a final engineering project and demonstrate my own robot working on ATMEL chip or ARM7 development board doing some basic navigational work using the ROS platform . I am completely new to this , i want to know how to stimulate it using the ROS and how to write the source code for it .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48694/designing-your-own-robot-using-ros-platform./) by [Ank_khandelwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3633/ank_khandelwal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome to ROS Answers. I would suggest first investigating ROS Wiki and get an idea of what hardware systems and OS platforms it is compatible with.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/

Then you might want to see how other people are utilizing ROS (youtube is a good resource). Typically ROS robots running navigation (gmapping) require ROS running on a computer with some linux distro that usually is onboard the robot with sensors attached like kinect or laser scanners to create 2d/3d maps.

Give Turtlebot a good look over to get some ideas and capabilities for you project. There is also the Lego NXT if you do not want to invest too much in hardware, it may be more similar to what you have in mind.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2